# MotionEvent getActionIndex() is always ACTION_DOWN

Tags: android

Hello Im trying to use setOnClickListener on one of my views.

My problem is that I always get ACTION_DOWN index.

I checked about its mainly happen because you need to return true in the onTouch. But I return true and I still dont get other indexes.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         switch (arg1.getActionIndex()) 
            {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                {

                    Log.i("test", "down");

                    return true;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

                    Log.i("test", "up");

                    return true;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

                    Log.i("test", "move");

                    return true;
                }
            }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should switch on `getAction()`  not on `getActionIndex()`. Is `getAction()` that does return the kind of action being performed.